# Issue using FPDF2 with python.barcode

Tags: python, fpdf

Using FPDF2 to generate a document that requires a Code39 barcode:

```
from barcode import Code39
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from fpdf import FPDF
from io import BytesIO

...

pdf = new PDF()
pdf.add_page()
rv = BytesIO()
Code39("TEST",writer=ImageWriter()).write(rv)
pdf.image(rv,10,10,100)
pdf.output(name="test.pdf")
```

There are no errors; however, the barcode is not included in the document.  Is there another or better approach to getting this done?  Thanks!